# How Should I Add Toastr to my Angular 2/MVC Application

Tags: javascript, webpack, toastr

I am developing a project using Steve Sanderson's excellent template as a starting point ([Angular Template for Visual Studio](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)). I want to add Toastr functionality ([Toastr)](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) but every time I try and use it I get an error that "toastr is not defined".

I went about the following:

1. Added a dependency for `"toastr": "2.1.2"` to my `package.json` file.
2. Added both `"toastr"` (for the javascript) and `"toastr/build/toastr.min.css"` (for the css) to my `webpack.config.vendor.json` file.
3. From the command line ran `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`.

I checked inside my `vendor.css` and could clearly see toastr styles. I checked inside my `vendor.js` and could see toastr methods. My application references both my `vendor.css` and `vendor.js` files. In fact Angular and Bootstrap styling all works fine so the references should be good.

To test Toastr functionality I wrote a very simple script

```
<script>toastr.success('Success')</script>
```

and placed it after the `</body>` but I got a console error in, Chrome F12, that toastr was not defined. I also tried to run the script within a click handler in an Angular component but received the same error.

**Update**

In my simple `toastr.service.ts` file which I created I added an import statement as follows: `import * as toastr from "toastr";` and to prevent Typescript errors I then added: `declare let toastr: any;`.

The good news is My toastr service works. Frustratingly I have an error on my import statement saying "cannot find module toastr". Close.

Any suggestions why I am getting the warning and how to solve it very welcome.